# May I use a grade of service problem to calculate how many doctors are needed in a hospital?

Tags: probability, self-study, binomial-distribution, prediction

I created the following problem (based on grade of service problem of Intro to Prob by Tsitsiklis book):

original problem:
[image]

My analogy problem:

A Hospital unit has 15 doctors to serve the needs of a population of 100. It is estimated that at a given time, each inhabitant will need to go to the doctor with probability .1,
independent of the others. What is the probability that there are more inhabitants
needing to be served than there are doctors?

Is it correct to use this model to answer a different problem like the one I created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @gunes (+1) has said: Taken exactly as stated, you have the same question
either way. $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=100, p=0.1)$ is
the probability a modem/doctor will be busy at a given
time. And you seek $P(X > 15) = 1 - P(X \le 15) = 0.0399.$
In R, where `pbinom` is a binomial CDF, the computation
is shown below:

```
1 - pbinom(15,100,.1)
[1] 0.03989053
```

However, neither model deals explicitly with the period
of time over which a modem/doctor may be engaged.

Also, in the hospital situation it seems artificial to
say the the potential population served is 100 people.
It might be better to get data to estimate the rate at
which patients arrive for doctors' services and model the number needing
service at any one time as Poisson.  For example, if records show the Poisson mean to be $\lambda = 9.5,$ so that $Y \sim
\mathsf{Pois}(\lambda =9.5),$ then $P(Y > 15) = 0.0335.$

```
1 - ppois(15,9.5)
[1] 0.033473
```

If you want to take into account the average 'service time'
of doctors, then you would need a queueing model with
appropriate rate of arrival and rate of service by a doctor.
Then the issues become the percentage of time there are more than
15 patients in the system, necessitating a queue (waiting line)
of patients, and the average waiting time in the queue.

Comment: I liked how you explored more the question.

Comment: How could I put into words this probability? Something like e.g.: could I interpret 0.03989053 (~0.04) probability as "for every 100 patients who come to the hospital 4 would have to wait if the hospital has 15 doctors" ? or as 'if someone came 100 times at the hospital 4 times this patient would have to wait.'?

Comment: Those are reasonable statements. Because it refers to the general population, I like the first one best. I might say 'about 4' instead of '4'.

Comment: The problem can be answered by a binomial probability because we may state as 'A person may need a doctor or not' ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, basically you've just changed the objects:

- modem $\rightarrow$ doctor
- customer $\rightarrow$ patient

And, since $n,c,p$ are the same, your probability is $\approx 0.04$ as well.

Comment: gunes, thank you

Comment: How could I put into words this probability? Something like e.g.: could I interpret 0.03989053 (~0.04) probability as "for every 100 patients who come to the hospital 4 would have to wait if the hospital has 15 doctors" ? or as 'if someone came 100 times at the hospital 4 times this patient would have to wait.'?

Comment: there is a 4 % chance that some patients will not find a doctor